# HTML Coding not Centering Widget Properly - Please save my sanity

Tags: javascript, html

I am working to get an object I retrieved from 100 Widgets centered on a webpage. It's a clock. I am working in TeamSite. The object will not center properly. When I type the HTML coding to center the object the preview mode changes it to being centered, however when I publish the item, the website will not reflect the adjustment "live". It remains left aligned; except in *Preview mode* where it will remain centered properly.
Here's what I have (it's very simple, so it's making me crazy!):

```
<div style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;">    
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://100widgets.com/js_data.php?id=38"> 
  </script>    
</div>
```

Spaces were added to allow text viewing. I've also tried to be very basic including just `<center>` and `</center>`. I get the same result. This clock is located: http://100widgets.com/clocks/page/2/ and is called Clock Blue and White.
Can someone please tell me what's wrong with this thing before I go completely insane?! Lol...but for real.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That should center the `div` element on the page, though it may not center the content inside of it. Here are a few examples of how to center something horizontally.

```html
<style>body {margin:0;} </style>
<div style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;">1</div> <!-- centers the element based on the width -->
<div style="text-align:center">2</div> <!-- centers the inline content in the element -->
<div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%)">3</div> <!-- centers the element and the element is only as wide as the content inside -->
```

This is a good reference for centering stuff. https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: <div style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;text-align:center;"> will work, in OP case. Widget creates additional HTML, with one div, one link and embed object...:)